# R Shiny: Conditionally require user to select pickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity, shinywidgets

I have two `pickerInput` values in the app.  In the first, `geography`, the user can select to view either `state` (default) or `county` data.  If the user selects `county`, I'd like to require that they pick a state from the second `pickerInput`, which is just a list of states.  It is not required that the user pick a state when `input$geography == "state"`.

I have considered putting this inside of a `modalDialogue` but it wasn't working.   I also tried an `updatePickerInput` which didn't work either.

What is the best way of conditionally requiring the user to select a value from a `pickerInput`?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I think you could use [`conditionalPanel`s](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html). If it does not work, then you should add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `shinyjs` :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  pickerInput("pick_1", choices = c("state","county"), multiple = FALSE, selected = "state"),
  shinyjs::hidden(
    pickerInput("pick_2", choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE)
  )


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    toggleElement("pick_2", condition = input$pick_1 == "state")

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```